# Dwell clicking software that supports right-dragging

Tags: mouse

I use [SmartNAV dwell clicking software](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/dwellclick.html), but it [doesn't support](http://forums.naturalpoint.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12696)  right-dragging. What dwell clicking software support right-dragging? Free and supporting Windows preferred.

---

A few definitions:

- Right-dragging = you click the right mouse button while pointing at something, hold down the right mouse button and drag the object somewhere
- [Dwell clicking](http://www.bltt.org/quicktips/mouse_dwell.htm) = Instead of having to press a mouse button or a switch the user needs to simply hold the mouse steady in an area for a predefined amount of time. This action issues the computer with a 'virtual' click and provides the same function as if someone had pressed the mouse button.

---

SmartNAV dwell clicking software:

[image]

> The dwell clicking toolbar is programmed to ‘Always Be on Top’. The Dwell toolbar gives you the option to (in order of appearance);
>   Pause Dwell Clicking, Single Click, Double Click, Drag, Right Click,
>   change Dwell Clicking options, Close Dwell Clicking, and move/drag the
>   Dwell Clicking button/tool bar to another location. We have already
>   discussed what the ‘pause’ and ‘dwell clicking options’ buttons do and
>   will now discuss the different clicking options.

More details [here](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/dwellclick.html).

Comment: How would you expect to activate right-click?

Comment: @MichaelKohne Info added in question, let me know if unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like free [Point-N-Click Virtual Mouse](http://polital.com/pnc/) has dragging using right button and dragging using middle button on its button bar.

Do not forget to set it to run **as administrator** on Windows 7 and higher.

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! We indeed need to run as administrator on Windows 7, it wouldn't work otherwise for me. It has more options than SmartNAV dwell clicking software except one to use for that I couldn't find: default to right click, left/right dragging or double click, which can be very useful sometime.